# php mysql session error

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have a piece of code which is running ok on localhost but it is not on my hosting server.

The issue seems to be with the following code??

```
<?php

session_start();

if( !isset( $_SESSION['username']) ){
   echo 'Unauthorized access';
   die();
   } 

?>
```

### I just get Unauthorized access even though login info is correct.

The following is code for login page.

```
<?php

include 'mysql_connect.php';

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM login WHERE username='$username' and password='$password'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count==1){
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password");
    header("location:edit-product.php");
}
else{
    echo "You have entered the wrong username or password";
}

?>
```

Comment: How are you setting the `$_SESSION` variables?

Comment: `session_register` is deprecated - use the `$_SESSION` superglobal instead like `$_SESSION['username'] = 'mikey'`

Comment: Also, your `location` header is wrong - it should be `header('Location: http://full.url/to/page.php');`

Answer (score 0):

`session_register` is depend on `register_globals` setting of your server( it will not work in environments where the PHP directive register_globals is disabled.). You can just use `$_SESSION['username'] = $username` to set the session value.

And you need `session_start()` of every page which you are using session.

And there is sql injection in your code.

Comment: "And there is sql injection in your code". And the password isn't hashed.

Answer (score 0):

session_register has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0. Check the PHP version on your server.
You should use

```
$_SESSION['username'] = true;
$_SESSION['password'] = true;
```

Or something like that.

On the other hand you should at least sanitize your input with mysql_real_escape_string() or better yet use prepared statements.